# Calculate age from birthdate 

Tags: jquery

I have two textboxes. The first one is a date, the second one is an age. I have 2 cases :

- I know the birthdate, I fill in the textbox and the age is calculated and displayed in the second textbox, this textbox is readonly
- I don't know the birthdate, I enter an age, no birthdate and no more action

Do you have an idea for the first point ?

Comment: what is the format of the date that will be entered? and if the input date has a standard format, why can't you just split the string, get the year-of-birth and find the difference ?

Comment: @Tarun: Say I was born on July 1st, 2000. It's now May 23rd, 2011. How old am I?

Comment: yes, so what I'm asking is, is the format standard? is the input format generalized to `[month date],[year]`

Answer (score 2):

Kris,

I had a similar issue and used this page as a ref a while ago:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

or this:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/623

just wrap your call inside the required jquery button click etc.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library

Answer (score 0):

```
--markup--
<input id = "eAge" type = "text"/>
<input type=  "button" id = "fAge"  value = "find"/>
<input id = "age" type = "text"/>

--jQuery --

$("#fAge").click(function() {
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var year = $("#eAge").val().split(',');
    $("#age").val(currentYear - year[1]);
});
```

here's the jsFiddle link to it -- http://jsfiddle.net/GGgqx/

hope it helped

Comment: what was the input you gave? and the solution I have given is based on input which is of the format `[month date],[year]` , you'll have to customize it as per your requirement :)

Comment: -1 Because your solution does not calculate whether the entered value has already happened during the calendar year

Answer (score 0):

My function:

```
$('#txtFecha').focusout(function () {

        var fecha = document.getElementById('txtFecha').value;
        var edad = '';

        //supose my date is dd/mm/yyyy
        if ((fecha.substring(2,3) != "/") && (fecha.substring(5,6) != "/")) {
            edad = '';
        }
        else {
            var dia = fecha.substring(0, 2);
            var mes = fecha.substring(3, 5);
            var anio = fecha.substring(6, 10);
            var diaActual = (new Date).getDay();
            var mesActual = (new Date).getMonth();
            var anioActual = (new Date).getFullYear();

            if (mes > mesActual)
                edad = anioActual - anio - 1;

            if (mesActual == mes && dia > diaActual)
                edad = anioActual - anio - 1;

            edad = anioActual - anio;

            if (edad < 0 || edad > 100)
                edad = '';

        }
        $("#txt2Edad").val(edad);

    });
```